Problem with Shared Pointer when using conditions
Im currently working on my Game Engine and have started to implement fundamental functions for my Entity Component System. I want to have a method which adds  new components. To be sure that only valid types could be added to the list i used an if statement.But while testing this function it threw me an error: C2655 no overloaded function could convert all the argument types .I dont get why it gives me that error, since the else block will only be executed when the type is valid.
template<typename T>
    void AddComponent() {
        bool state = std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value;
        if (!state) {
            std::string TypeName = typeid(T).name();
            LOGERROR(TypeName + " IS NOT A COMPONENT");
            return;
        }
        else {
            std::string TypeName = typeid(T).name();
            LOG(TypeName + " IS A COMPONENT");
            componentList.emplace_back(std::make_shared<T>());
        }
    }

int main(void)
{
    //For example i added an invalid type Camera. 
    GameObject* gameObject = new GameObject;
    gameObject->AddComponent<Camera>();
    delete gameObject;
}

Some more details:
-Addcomponent is a member of GameObject
-Components are stored as shared pointers in a vector.
-T should only be added if its derive from Component class (e.x. Transform)
I tried many different things but I couldnt solve it yet

Provide a [mcve]

if constexpr for dripping the code that should not try to be compiled.

THANKS IT WORKS NOW. But whats actually different now ???? why did "if constexpr" work but just "if" not?

if constexpr is a compile-time check, and the compiler discards code for the condition(s) that test false.  A raw if is a run-time check, so the compiler cannot discard code for conditions that test false, and such code may include (for the types for which they test false) diagnosable errors.

Side note, learn not to use new/delete GameObject* gameObject = new GameObject; but use auto gameObject = std::make_unique<GameObject>();, though in this case you probably should not dynamicall allocate anyway since your GameObject has the same life cycle as the scope of your main (Useless use of new).  So just use GameObject gameObject{};

Yes i have to wrap my had around about memory allocation. i switched from c# to c++ 4 weeks ago. .Huge thanks to all of you helping me <3

C# references are somewhat semantically similar to C++ std::shared_ptr.  However, I caution against using std::shared_ptr except as the smart pointer of last resort — when you use it because you have to use it.  Try to bias in favor of std::unique_ptr and strong single ownership.  And only use raw pointers as non-owning pointers.  Good luck on your adventure of learning C++: the hardest to learn (yet popular!) general programming language.
